# django cannot import name patterns on app engine as app is working fine on heroku but not working on app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am learning django and i have deployed it on heroku it is working fine here it is the link http://whispering-bayou-9769.herokuapp.com/ but on app engine it is not working giving me error 
500 please try again in few time

it is the url for app engine http://djangocomment.appspot.com/

Please help me i think it may be problem of app.yml because on app engine logs there is log telling me error

'exceptions.ImportError'>: cannot import name pattern i have check url.py it is fine already working on heroku

in app.yml i have wriiten

```
application: djangocomment
runtime: python
version: 1
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: /post/urls.py


env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'post.settings'
```

urls.p[y in post folder contain the path

file structure

```
app/
   build/


   categopry/
     admin.py
    templates/
    models.py
    urls.py
    tests.py
  post/
    urls.py
    forms.py
    settings.py
    wsgi.py

   static/
    admin.py
    templates/
    models.py
    urls.py
    tests.py

   template/
      registration/

   userprofile/
     admin.py
    templates/
    models.py
    urls.py
    tests.py

   app.yml

  manage.py
  procfile
  README.md
  requiremtn.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

That really isn't how you run a Django app on GAE. What gave you the idea to point the script to urls.py?

For a start, you need to reference Django in the `libraries` setting in your app.yaml. Then, you need to set the `script` to the WSGI object within your project's wsgi.py file: perhaps something like `post.wsgi.app`. See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#django).

Comment: hi in app.yaml i have added this in handler handlers:
- url: .*
  script: djangocomment.wsgi.app as the app name is djangocomment on the app engine now i am getting this error File referenced by handler not found: djangocomment.wsgi.app so can you tel the thing need to write in app.yaml

Comment: Please can you post the full file/directory structure of your app (as an update to your question).

Comment: hi check i have update dmy post with directory structure also if you want i can send you drop box link for the thing alsso it is working on heroku just i am trying to learn app engine deployment also so getting this problem

Comment: The WSGI file appears to be inside `post`, for some reason. So your script should be `post.wsgi.app`, as I said originally.

Comment: I am getting this error now on google console File referenced by handler not found: post.wsgi.py handlers:
- url: .*
  script: post.wsgi.py

Comment: have you any other idea why it is happening